# S3 bucket with public access return 403 forbidden error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I'm using S3 bucket with pulic access and without any permissions, it wordked for years, but  now I get 403 error.Maybe someone
occurred this error? Can't upload any image or pdf file.
This is the CORS configuration.

````
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
] ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible that someone has changed the **permissions** on your S3 bucket, or on the objects in the bucket, to prevent public access. This could have been done accidentally or maliciously.

You may follow the steps to troubleshoot your issue.

1. **Check the Block Public Access settings**: Make sure that the Block
   Public Access settings do not prevent public access to the bucket
   or its objects.
2. **Try uploading a file from a different IP address**: If you are able to
   upload a file from a different **IP address**, then it is possible that
   your original IP address has been blocked.
3. Make sure that the **AllowedOrigins** list includes the origin from where
   you are trying to upload the files. If you are using a **wildcard (*)**,
   then you may need to add the specific origin to the list.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this is not my cases, I change the nodeJs version recently from 14 to 18. Do you think this can cause a problem with S3 bucket?